# Could not chdir to home directory /export/home/wjones: Permission denied

Tags: solaris

Only root can loginto SSH terminal no created user can access the terminal how can I alter permissions to allow users to log in as well

```
Could not chdir to home directory /export/home/UserName: Permission denied
```

I have listed the permissions below for root user and some of the file users on the system

```
ls -la /export/home 


# ls -la /export/home
total 126206
drwx------ 573 root     root         577 Jan 28 12:46 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     sys          512 Jul 29  2011 ..
drwx------   2 Cmont    student        7 Aug 26 14:07 Cmont
drwx------   2 Rcampbell01 student        7 Aug 21  2018 Rcampbell01
drwx------  24 WS01     student      119 Jan 23 10:04 WS01
drwx------  19 WS02     student       90 Nov 25 08:27 WS02
drwx------  23 WS03     student      193 Jan 23 10:10 WS03
drwx------  22 WS04     student      179 Jan 23 10:06 WS04
drwx------  20 WS05     student      124 Jan 23 10:08 WS05
drwx------  26 WS06     student      147 Jan 23 10:07 WS06
drwx------  24 WS07     student      162 Jan 23 10:06 WS07
drwx------  22 WS08     student      144 Jan 23 10:05 WS08
drwx------  24 WS09     student      162 Jan 23 10:05 WS09
drwx------  23 WS10     student      150 Jan 21 12:52 WS10
```

Comment: You might get a better answer asking your institution's IT Services

Comment: You're not showing how you create the accounts. Are you doing it as the root user on the machine? Are the home directories actually created? What are their permissions? What command are you running when that diagnostic message appears?

Comment: I create accounts as the root user in a script where the directory is created. Its almost as if only ME the Root user has permissions no other user can log on

Comment: This would be so much easier to debug if you could show the script that created the user accounts. Also, this is the first time that you say that people have issues logging in.  In the question you say that _creating_ an account throws an error.

Comment: I worded my question wrong earlier and I noticed the actual problem is that only the Root can log into the terminal no user can access it. So it has to do with the permissions not letting users log in

Comment: Why do you show and check `/home` when you are using `/export/home`?

Comment: Showing the actual _code_ that you use to create the accounts would be helpful.

Comment: As a side note : _never_ log in via SSH as root.

Comment: @schaiba there are sometimes good reasons to do so. _Never_ is too strong.

Answer (score 2):

The permissions for the directory `/export/home` are too strict. Only the root user has access to that directory.

Fix it with something like this

```
chmod go+rx /export/home
```

Answer (score -1):

Home directories are typically under `/home` and automatically `loopback` mounted from the original location.

The original location of the users home directory is either under `/export/home` or on a NFS server.

Such a directory needs to be created by the system administrator who has the needed rights and who can `chown` the directory to be accessible by the new user.

Note: You need to have a correct entry in `/etc/auto_home` to tell the automounter what to do. For a local home directory, the related entry looks like:

```
*       localhost:/pool/home/&
```

or in your case:

```
*       localhost:/export/home/&
```

Your sysadmin did use an improper file permission for `/export/home`, since the listed permission does not even allow to search through `/export/home` for normal users. You need at least:

```
rwx--x--x
```

for `/export/home`.